# facing broken link issue on git

Tags: git, corruption

Facing issue on git. I am working on laravel project and using git with it and it works perfectly fine when I am on ubuntu 22. 2 days ago I switch from ubuntu 22 to 20. From that time my git is showing me issue like this. Whenever i do

```
git status
```

facing this errors

```
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-6b68024d008ad2eeb7b868426394f7b05ceffcd7.pack does not match index
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-6b68024d008ad2eeb7b868426394f7b05ceffcd7.pack does not match index
fatal: unable to read tree ff1d9cabfbc6a18a4395439ca7dcbe70caff31f4
```

I also run this command:

```
git fsck --full
```

which shows me this errors:

```
error: refs/heads/master: invalid reflog entry ed59e4f61af1df9468d3931fd65e620d12237d38
error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry d052791061460d99dfb53cf5039f6bdf8eb8291d
broken link from    tree 4f9d43e0ca6b72791f48bed0eff01a077d6d69f0
          to    blob 8f0de65c560259bd171d746d12aa187f666893a3
missing tree 76f5d89c7e80b1bc66779249259c7ec90d5bae3c
dangling blob 77dd35c4a722298b2d02d9aff737f5a591fae604
```

I tried all the stuff from internet but nothing solve
help me please how I can recover these issues

Answer (score 0):

Is your target repo up to date or near current? If so in some cases, when a repository is seriously corrupted, it might be easier to clone the repository again and then move over your changes manually. Clone your repository into a new directory. Then, you can copy your modified files from the old repository to the new one.

If the issues still persist, you might want to try checking out a different branch or commit to see if the issue is specific to your current branch or commit. If you can successfully checkout a different branch or commit, it might indicate that the issue is localized to a certain part of your repository's history.

If you want to do before these:

- You might want to consider deleting the packfile causing the issue, and after that, run the `git fsck` command again. Locate the file named `pack-6b68024d008ad2eeb7b868426394f7b05ceffcd7.pack` within your repository's `.git/objects/pack/` directory, and proceed to remove this specific file.
- Run the following commands to prune and rebuild the repository's object database:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: All the errors are gone, but this still persists
fatal: unable to read tree ff1d9cabfbc6a18a4395439ca7dcbe70caff31f4

Actually my repository have commits of last 1 august, not have after this. In this case i can't clone from repository. because i have made several changes in local

Comment: Attempt to check out the relevant commit or branch again (`git checkout ff1d9cabfbc6a18a4395439ca7dcbe70caff31f4
`) If you don't encounter any errors at this step, you can save the necessary changes to a different branch and then switch back to the main branch. If you're still encountering errors, you can try repairing the objects: `git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found
` This command will extract unreachable and lost objects to a directory named `lost-found` You can inspect and potentially recover the necessary objects from this directory. Ensure have a backup of your data